# js: Regex to find a string in Knockout conditional comments

Tags: javascript, regex, knockout.js

I have to find a string in the Knockout conditional comment using Regex. The scenario is , There will be two kind of **KnockoutConditionalStatement**, this will vary based upon the user details **paid/not-paid**.

Statement-I - Not-paid

```
<!-- ko if: IsPaidUser() --><!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: !IsPaidUser() -->
<!-- ko if: $parent.isEditable($data.UserName, $data.UserRole) -->
<i title="NotPaid" class="fa fa-toggle-on faIcons fa-rotate-180 toggleOff" data bind="click: function (data, event) { $parent.toggleUserAccountStatus($index(), 'reactivate') }"></i>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: !$parent.isEditable($data.UserName, $data.UserRole) --><!-- /ko -->
<i style="display: none;">00</i>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Statement-II - Paid

```
<!-- ko if: IsPaidUser() -->
<!-- ko if: $parent.isEditable($data.UserName, $data.UserRole) -->
<i title="Paid" class="fa fa-toggle-on faIcons green" data-bind="click: function (data, event) { $parent.toggleUserAccountStatus($index(), 'deactivate') }"></i>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: !$parent.isEditable($data.UserName, $data.UserRole) --><!-- /ko -->
<i style="display: none;">01</i>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: !IsPaidUser() --><!-- /ko -->
```

Based upon the user details, Statement-I or Statement-II will be saved in the status

```
var status = knockoutConditionalStatement;
```

Task is,

1. have to check whether the user is Paid Customer or Not-paid Customer
2. have to check whether the status having word "NotPaid" or "Paid" knockoutConditionalStatement
3. if word "Not-paid" found in knockoutConditionalStatement means have to set the License as false
4. if word "Paid" found knockoutConditionalStatement means have to set the License as true

I have tried like Method -I,

```
var status = knockoutConditionalStatement;
var license = false;
if (string.search("title=\"Paid\""))
{
    license = true;
}

else
{
    license = false;
}
// this code run without any error. but license mode did not analysed.
```

I have also tried like this method -II, (may be stupid)

```
if(String == '<!-- ko if: IsPaidUser() --><!-- /ko --><!-- ko if: !IsPaidUser() --><!-- ko if: $parent.isEditable($data.UserName,$data.UserRole) --><i title="NotPaid" class="fa fa-toggle-on faIcons fa-rotate-180toggleOff" data-bind="click: function (data, event) { $parent.toggleUserAccountStatus($index(), 'reactivate')}"></i><!-- /ko --><!-- ko if: !$parent.isEditable($data.UserName, $data.UserRole) --><!-- /ko --><i style="display: none;">00</i><!-- /ko -->')
{
    license = true;
}

else
{
    license = false;
}
// this code always getting into else{} block
```

Please suggest me how can I parse the knockout Conditional Statement and predict the license details.

Thanks in Advance

**EDIT- 1: Working code:**

```
var status = knockoutConditionalStatement;
var license = false;
    if (string.search("title=\"Paid\"") != -1 ) // if found
    {
        license = true;
    }

    else // not found
    {
        license = false;
    }
```

Comment: Can't you parse the statement and use `i.title == "Paid"` afterwards?

Comment: Thanks Jan, For reply. Okay.Is there any other way/idea to do it ?

Comment: This makes no sense to me. Why would you parse html in your view model code? Just use view model properties (e.g. `IsPaid`) instead...

Comment: This is my case, If the user is paid customer then the fa-toggle will be on and looks green in color. If not a paid customer means it will be in grey color fa-toggle will be off. So I have to sense the fa-toggle state on/off then detect the license status of the customer.

Comment: Method one works fine for me now, The place I did mistake is `if(string.search("title=\"Paid\""))`, which results some positive number for success case and -1 for failure case, Anyhow it is non zero so only all time only one block executed. Now i made it like, `if(string.search("title=\"Paid\"") != -1)` Now once term is found it is going to the true block, if not it is going to the else block